# Custom created TransactionId are getting duplicated SQL SERVER when multiple users trying to insert data

Tags: c#, sql

I am facing one issue in one of my application. For every record we save to database(SQL Server) we create on TransactionID manually through code. The format is like 170613-1001, Todays date-4 digit auto incremented ID. Table is its own primary Key. However when multiple users trying save data in bulk, some of TransactionID's are getting duplicated. I observed time stamp of such records, these are exactly same. I tried to generate TransactionID's from Stored procedure before insert, but still TransactionID are getting duplicated. How to resolve this issue.

Comment: 1001 is `PrimaryKey` of your `table` and it's auto increment ?

Comment: No, I just have given example as 1001, Its not related to primary key. For every day it starts with 0001 and will increment by 1 for every transaction.

Comment: could you post your logic in details to create unique TransactionID

Comment: In this situation I also ask: is it really vital that your TransactionID resets every day? If you use IDENTITY or SEQUENCE in SQL Server all your troubles will go away, but first you need to get over having to reset it every day. If you want you could even add a lookup table in parallel that maps each IDENTITY value to any convoluted key that you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Sequence.GetNextValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql) to generate transaction id. It will be transaction safe and will not be repeated.